# Should i stay in a job that i do not like, just because it is a big company and the experience gained would be valuable in future

Tags: resume, work-experience

What to do in a situation where you do not like your job but you also realize that experience and skills gained in the job would be valuable in future career?

I am right now in a similar situation.

I don't like my job, feel undervalued and underpaid/overworked. But i am afraid of leaving because the experience gained in this position would look very good on my cv and can potentially be very valuable in the future. (Its one of the biggest company working in oil and gas sector in our country).

Should i stay in a job that i do not like, just because it is a big company and the experience gained would be valuable in future?

Comment: Is it just me or is working in an environment where you gain valuable skills not the definition of a good job?? Or am i missing something. Maybe your question is actually on the "underpaid/overworked" aspect??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to say that the stay-leave decision will be based on several factors.

First how long have you been there? And how long have you stayed at other jobs. No one wants to hire a job hopper who is never happy anywhere, so if you have a history of short-term jobs, I would consider staying longer at this one.

Second - how valuable really is the experience you are getting and is it something you can get somewhere else relatively easily right now? For instance I took a job specifically to get some experience with SQL Server when I did not have large database experience; I stayed until I had the experience to not be a beginner elsewhere because it was in my best interests to get that experience in what I wanted to specialize in because it is not easy to find a job when you are changing career paths. Another case might be your first management position. If you want to stay in management, you don't want to leave this one early because you need some management success to show to a new employer to get to the next level of management, but if you want to go back to technical it might not be a problem.

Just because a company is large doesn't automatically mean you are getting the right experience for you. If you have a plan for particular steps you need to take along the way, then you can put up with less than optimum conditions to get to the point where you are experienced enough that you can pick and choose. But don't stay just because the company is well-known or large. Stay because there is something specific that you need from that job before you move on.

Another consideration is that the grass is often not greener elsewhere. You think you are underpaid and overworked. Well honestly, so do most people. There are probably better places than the one you are in, but I assure you that there are much worse places, too. Take the time to really consider what you want in a workplace and how you would figure out if that is what a company is offering before you jump from the frying pan into the fire. Be much pickier about your next position.

Of course in order to be really picky and get the postion at the best companies you have to have something extraordinary to offer. If you want to work for the best, you are in competition with the best as well. Think about whether it might be a better use of your time to stay where you are and get those qualifications than a string of jobs you hate. Short-term unhappiness is sometimes a good trade-off for long-term success.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not.  I have stayed and I have left jobs.  I can say, that after having almost 10 different jobs over 20 years, the one I held onto the longest, through the darkest days was the worst.

If you are not happy, you are not productive, you are not pushing yourself, you are not growing.  When this happens for long enough you will find that you can't find another job either.

Don't quit before you have that replacement job, but don't think there is something holding you back.  Go out there and find a better job.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I particularly agree about the productivity part. My unhappiness lack of interest shows in my work and my performance is starting to suffer.